# How does apache 2 server process http GET request?

Tags: apache, iot

I was trying an IOT project where in I want to update the database remotely using ESP8266-01 module. I have the php file to update the database, but to execute that I am trying with GET method. Unfortunately, it wan't working. The server received the request in the access.log, but wan't updating the database. Wanted to debug, so I had this question.

The entry in the access.log is as follows:

192.168.43.150 - - [18/Mar/2017:20:23:40 +0000] "GET collectdata.php?status=1 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.43.92\r\n\r\n" 400 0 "-" "-"

Comment: Then answer your question if you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This looks wrong: `GET collectdata.php...`

That needs to be a full path, eg. `GET /collectdata.php` or `GET /scripts/collectdata.php`, or similar.

The 400 response code you're seeing in the log means "Bad request", and the lack of a leading slash (and the rest of the path, if needed) is what Apache is complaining about.

Comment: Did not work, now access.log has following entry:  192.168.43.150 - - [19/Mar/2017:04:49:02 +0000] "GET /collectdata.php?status=1 HTTP/1.1\\r\\nHost: 192.168.43.92\\r\\n\\r\\n" 400 0 "-" "-"

Comment: Suddenly you have double-backslashes everywhere...?

Comment: I had that before, but it dint appear before, and i failed to notice that until now. So what does that implies, the double backslashes?

Comment: I don't know.  Is your client code small enough that you could add it to the question?

Comment: Got the answer. The problem was with back-slash character, it was considering as two separate charterer. It was due to the serial monitor of arduino. Thanks for the support :)